# splitting angular controllers into their own variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

When you get to the routing and multiple views section they bring in the router but then also split out the controllers into a new var:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);
```

> To improve the organization of the app, we are making use of Angular's
>   ngRoute module and we've moved the controllers into their own module
>   phonecatControllers

I am half way through building my first angular app have decided that for organization purposes and speed of dev to house the controllers and services etc in the one var, and only include 3rd party modules in the dependencies bit:

```
var myFirstAngApp = angular.module('myFirstAngApp', [
    'wu.masonry',
    'slick',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource'
]);
```

Is there another reason to split out the controllers and services etc into their own variables as per the above mentioned tutorial, for speed purposes maybe?

Comment: Modularity. Different business logic for different section/view?

Comment: Softvar is right, you need to be able to manage code, your programs will get big and complicated pretty quickly, modularity of components help to ensure that when you change or fix on thing, other things don't break.  Think of each of these modules and components as having predefined inputs and outputs: when you change something inside, as long as the inputs and outputs remain correct, the rest of the app won't break because of that.

Comment: convention of using modules to group types of components is outdated...more common to group functionality into a module which makes modules more portable

Comment: additionally, if you keep them all in modules then the main app module contains a quickly identifiable manifest of the application's features. (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modularity)

Comment: that is a nice graphic there on the Module Dependencies bit thanks